# How to follow on Instagram directly from Android app?

Tags: android, instagram

I want to add a button to my android app that allows my app users to follow me on Instagram directly from my app. How do I do this? Currently I have this code that allows my app users to open my Instagram profile:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/" + R.string.instagram_id);
    Intent likeIng = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    likeIng.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

    try {
        startActivity(likeIng);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/" + R.string.instagram_id)));
    }
```

Comment: Try finding the hyperlink Instagram generates for when you choose to follow a user and integrating that into your code? Or you could look up the transactions made via the browser using something like Firefox's Tamper Data and see if you can emulate those.

Comment: Oh, also try using the Instagram API. You'll probably have more luck there. www.instagram.com/developer/